# How to delete a folder at maven clean phase?

Tags: maven, maven-clean-plugin

I want do delete a folder at clean phase.

I have used `maven-clean-plugin` and successfully deleted all of the files under it.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>

            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>GENERATED_DIR</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I want to delete "GENERATED_DIR" as well.

Comment: At the risk of repeating the obvious: If you put your generated dir under `target`, you don't have problems like this. Generating dirs outside `target` should be a rare exception.

Comment: an external library generates that directory

Comment: The external library does not have a parameter to set the output directory?

Comment: Best is to check why an external library generates something into a directory which can't be configured ...Check the library if it can be changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This finally worked for me

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/GENERATED_DIR/**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

The following works for me

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <filesets>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>${basedir}/GENERATED_DIR</directory>
                </fileset>
            </filesets>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: with maven-clean-plugin version 3.0.0 does not work for me, what version do you use?

Comment: @aurelius the bundled version I get is 2.6.1 but it also works with 3.0.0, is the directory protected from the user that is running maven?

Comment: i don't see any related exceptions in the stack trace

Comment: <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/GENERATED_DIR/**</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>